# I can't get my ajax request to work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I cannot make the following AJAX request work:

I want to make the text entered in the field to be displayed in the "p" tag

Server: Apache 2.2
PHP 5

My HTML:

```html
<html>

<head>

  <title>Test for reponder</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    $function send() {
        $('body').on('click', 'button', function(event) {
              var namee = document.getElementById('name').value;
              //var dataString='name ='+ name;
              $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'responder.php',
                data: namee,
                success: function(html) {
                  $('#msg').html(html);
                }
              })
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="name">
  <!--<input type="submit" id="button" value="Send" onclick="return send();">-->
  <button type="button">Send</button>

  <p id="msg"></p>

</body>

</html>
```

My PHP file:

```html
<?php 
$name=$_POST[ 'name']; 
echo "response:" . $name; 
?>
```

Comment: `$function` is a syntax error, there's no such thing, remove the dollar sign, or better yet, don't put event handlers inside functions, other than a DOM ready handler

Comment: Check your browser console (F12) for Javascript errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="name">
<button type="button">Send</button>

<p id="msg"></p>
```

**jQuery**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on('click', 'button', function(){
            var name = $("#name").val();
            var param = {name: name};

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'responder.php',
                cache: 'false',
                data: param,

                beforeSend: function(){
                    // before send
                },

                success: function(data){
                    // success
                    $('#msg').html(data);
                },

                error: function(){
                    // error
                }
            });
        });
    });
 </script>
```

**responder.php**

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['name'])){
        $name=$_POST['name']; 
        echo "response:" . $name; 
    }

?>
```